# Unit test function with no return value jest

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs

I am making a react native app using expo, and wanted to do some jest unit testing. I have written the tests for my functions that have a return value, but now I am struggeling with functions that don't return anything. I have tried to google mocking funtions to try and somehow see which functions are called within the function, but with no luck. Does anyone have any tips on how to test functions like these? Thank you

[Examples of two functions that have no return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOWF7.png)

```
  const handleResponse = (response) => {
dispatch(resetResultScreen());
for (let user in response) {
  let userRatings = response[user];
  dispatch(addParticipant(user));
  for (let movieId in userRatings) {
    let rating = userRatings[movieId];
    dispatch(setTotalResults({ movieId: movieId, rating: rating }));
  }
}
dispatch(sortTotalResults());
dispatch(setLoading(false));
```

};

Comment: Give a [mre]. Presumably those functions still _do_ something, so test that - side effects, interactions with collaborators, ...

Comment: The functions are added in the image link, but I will add code snippets now as well! I have tested the dispatched functions already, I just need to check if the right ones are dispatched thorugh the funtion in the image

Comment: It looks like you're using Redux, so maybe have a look at https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests

Comment: Yes, I have used that to write tests for the functions that are called inside handleResponse, but I don't know how to test handleResponse itself.